# Angular component not reloading after login

Tags: angular

I have an Auth service that logs in, but it doesn't update the component live. Does Angular not do this?

The login component ts, not in ngOnInit:

```js
onSubmit() {
    this.authService.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(
    data => {
         this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
    },
    error => {
        this.error = error;
        this.loading = false;
    });
}
```

In the user components HTML file, I have

```
<ul class="logged-in" *ngIf="currentUser">
  <li>Logged in menu item</li>
</ul>
```

The user component ts:

```js
export class UserMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  currentUser: User;
  userFromApi: User;

  constructor(
      private userService: UserService,
      private authService: AuthService
  ) {
     this.currentUser = this.authService.currentUserValue;
  }

  UserMenu(){
    if(this.currentUser){
      this.userService.getById(this.currentUser.id).pipe(first()).subscribe(user => {
        this.userFromApi = user[0];
      });
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    // check user
    this.UserMenu();
  }
}
```

I'm importing everything correclyt, so I have left out some obvious code.

This works if I refresh it.

Comment: try removing `first()`

Comment: Can u share the value of currentUser

Comment: use this.router.navigate(**<rout>**); insted of this navihgate this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by `live` ? DO you mean login from one browser has to be informed to another browser ?

Comment: When and where is currentUser changed?

Comment: I want it to reload within the same browser. The component should update. without refresh, even if I didn't route it.

Comment: @NadhirFalta Removing first does not do anything.

Comment: @KapilDevNeupane I updated the post with the user component ts

Comment: What is this.returnUrl? should not it be data.returnUrl?

Comment: @Obaid No, it does not need data. It just needs to reload the component.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your code inside Angualar Zone.

In your login component,

```
onSubmit() {
   this.authService.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)
   .pipe(first())
   .subscribe(
      data => {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
    });

},
error => {
    this.error = error;
    this.loading = false;
});
}
```

And in constructor

```
constructor(private  zone: NgZone) {}
```